# Discord bot cant find/doesn't have permissions to a channel even though it does

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

VSCode, python 3.9.2. heres the code, not sure what else to say:

```
import sys
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

discord_module_path = r'C:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages'
if discord_module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(discord_module_path)
print(sys.path)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
TOKEN = "no token for you"

def currentTimetableDay(startDate, currentDate):
    difference = currentDate - startDate
    schoolDaysPassed = difference.days // 7 * 5
    remainingDays = difference.days % 7
    for day in range(1, remainingDays + 1):
        nextDay = startDate + timedelta(days=day)
        if nextDay.weekday() < 5:
            schoolDaysPassed += 1
    
    currentDayIndex = schoolDaysPassed % len(Timetable)
    return currentDayIndex + 1

def printCurrentItem(currentTime, currentDay):
    if currentTime == "08:54":
        if currentDay != 5:  # Ignore the first item if it's Friday
            return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][0]
    elif currentTime == "09:49":
        return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][1]
    elif currentTime == "11:09":
        return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][2]
    elif currentTime == "11:59":
        return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][3]
    elif currentTime == "13:29":
        return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][4]
    elif currentTime == "18:05": #14:19
        return DaySupplies[currentDay - 1][5]
    else:
        return None

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as ", bot.user.name)
    await main_loop()

async def main_loop():
    while True:
        currentTime = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        print("Current time:", currentTime)  # Debug statement
        currentDay = currentTimetableDay(StartDate, datetime.now())
        print("Current day:", currentDay)  # Debug statement

        # Check if it's a weekday and the time matches any of the specified times
        if datetime.now().weekday() < 5 and currentTime in ["08:54", "09:49", "11:09", "11:59", "13:29", "18:05"]:
            next_subject = printCurrentItem(currentTime, currentDay)
            if next_subject:
                await send_message_to_discord(next_subject)
            else:
                print("No subject found for the current time.")
        
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check the time every 60 seconds

async def send_message_to_discord(subject):
    channel = bot.get_channel("channel id WAS here")  # Replace with your channel ID
    if channel:
        await channel.send(f"Next subject: {subject}")
    else:
        print("Channel not found or bot doesn't have access to the channel.")

Timetable = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6"]
DaySupplies = [
    ["Digital Tech", "English", "Science", "Tech", "Social Studies"],           # DAY 1
    ["DVC", "English", "Science", "Japanese", "Social Studies", "Maths"],       # DAY 2
    ["English", "Science", "Tech", "SocialStudies", "Maths", "Digital Tech"],   # DAY 3
    ["PE", "Japanese", "Social Studies", "Maths", "DVC", "English"],            # DAY 4
    ["Tech", "Social Studies", "Maths", "Digital Tech", "English", "Science"],  # DAY 5
    ["PE", "Maths", "DVC", "English", "Science", "Japanese"]                    # DAY 6
]

StartDate = datetime(2024, 3, 15)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

it only breaks when the message is sent, it logs in fine.

i tried setting every possible permission i could to administrator

stackoverflow wants more words aiuhawd ahudw ajwidijg ogijrei eurgheijg eigjeig iuhef. eorvjeorv, ihevnneve enveivniev.

Comment: When the system asks you for more information, you should probably check [ask] and then [edit] your question and add more information. Adding random garbage is not likely to help you; some people like me may even downvote you just for that, as it shows your complete unwillingness to get familiar with the site rules and post a reasonable question.